# Pythonic way to cast a dictionary into a pd.DataFrame with two columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hash-map

I have a dictionary where for each key, a single value is stored. Say

```
import pandas as pd
dd = {'Alice': 40,
      'Bob': 50,
      'Charlie': 35}
```

Now, I want to cast this dictionary to a pd.Dataframe with *two* columns. The first column contains the keys of the dictionary, the second column the values and give the columns a name (Say "Name" and "Age"). I expect to have a function call like:

```
 pd.DataFrame(dd, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

which gives not desired output, since it only has 0 rows.

Currently I have two "solutions":

```
# Rename the index and reset it:
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index', columns=['Age']).rename_axis('Name').reset_index()
pd.DataFrame(list(dd.items()), columns=['Name', 'Age'])

# Both result in the desired output:
    Name    Age
0   Alice   40
1   Bob     50
2   Charlie 35
```

However, both appear a bit hacky and thus inefficient and error-prone to me. Is there a more pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong/hacky in using `pd.DataFrame(dd.items(), columns=['Name', 'Age'])` to get the needed result in your case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Didn't realize that ```list()´´´´ can be removed. Without this, it seems to be ok for me. Do you want to post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Honestly, it's too simple to be a significant answer.